# Indefinite integral $\int x^3 * {e^x}^2dx$

Tags: integration

$\int x^3*{e^x}^2dx$ (e to the power of x to the power of 2)$

$u = x^3, u'= 3x^2$

$v'= {e^x}^2, v =2x{e^x}^2$

I don't understand the process of calculating this integral as I keep returning to the integration by parts. Is there a better way to calculate it?

Comment: Try $u = x^2, v' = xe^{x^2}$.